# Gradient operator is it continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces

The following gradient operator is it continuous?
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\nabla  :& H^1_0(\Omega) & \longrightarrow &(L^2(\Omega))^n\\
& y & \longmapsto   &  \displaystyle(\frac{\partial y(x)}{\partial x_1},
\frac{\partial y(x)}{\partial x_2}, ..., \frac{\partial y(x)}{\partial x_n})
\end{array}
and how could i prove that it is continuous?

Comment: trivialy yes by defintion of all norms

Comment: please, how could i prove that it is continuous?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{array}{ccccc}
\nabla  :& H^1_0(\Omega) & \longrightarrow &(L^2(\Omega))^n\\
& y & \longmapsto   &  \displaystyle(\frac{\partial y(x)}{\partial x_1},
\frac{\partial y(x)}{\partial x_2}, ..., \frac{\partial y(x)}{\partial x_n})
\end{array}

\begin{array}{ccccc}
\|\nabla u\|^2_{(L^2(\Omega))^n} =\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \displaystyle\int_\Omega\Big|\frac{\partial u(x)}{\partial x_i}\Big|^2 dx\le \|u\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \displaystyle\int_\Omega\Big|\frac{\partial u(x)}{\partial x_i}\Big|^2 dx  = \|u\|^2_{H^1_0(\Omega)}
\end{array}

That is 
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\|\nabla u\|_{(L^2(\Omega))^n} \le\|u\|_{H^1_0(\Omega)}
\end{array}